# Dynamically connect to any access database in java

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc

I want the user to be able to browse the `.mdb` file (access database file containing a single table) and then read the name of the table, the fields of the table and their values and display them in a grid in Java.

How can I do this? It should work for any `.mdb` file which user provides as input.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a broad question but the technolgies that would be key are:

- JDBC - for database access
- JDBC->ODBC Bridge - to allow connectity to the Jet database (access)

Then look at Hibernate for ORM mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Jackcess](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/). I never used it personally but it looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

Commercial HXTT Access at http://www.hxtt.com/access.html , which supports MS Access 95~2010.